# Trying to import sql-script into existing database generates error

Tags: mysql, symfony, phpmyadmin

I have following sql-script:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Soccerproject`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Soccerproject`.`user` (
  `userName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `money` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `userid_UNIQUE` (`userid` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `userName_UNIQUE` (`userName` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However I get this error when I try to import it:

```
#1142 - CREATE command denied to user '*****'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

Googeling did not resolve my issue ...

Comment: which mysql user are you using to run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user does not have privileges to create tables in that database.  [The MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) show you the syntax for granting permissions to a user, so give that a try.

you can do something like this:

```
GRANT CREATE ON <dbname> TO 'Stijnxk59'@'<dbhost>';
```

this will give the user CREATE privileges, but you can add ALTER privileges and any others you want.  Or you can even grant ALL privileges, it just depends what you want to allow that user to do.

Comment: or, you could also run the script as the `root` user.  But I wouldn't use the `root` user as the user in your application

Comment: where ever you run your queries from.  You can do it from the mysql command line, or you can do it from phpmyadmin.